# Try/catch not working during asset loading

Tags: exception, audio, xna, xna-4.0

During the loading of a sound effect (in C#, XNA) using:

```cs
SoundEffect effect = Content.Load<SoundEffect>(location);
```

on certain computers with a specific sound setup, I get application crashes throwing an `InvalidOperationException` exception. The content manager seems properly initialized and the location is also correct (works fine on different computer).

A example audio file is available at: http://www.hybridbeasts.com/test.wav

Interestingy, a try/catch fails and still produces an application crash.

```cs
try
{
    effect = Content.Load<SoundEffect>(location);
}
catch
{
    Warning.Happened("Problem with audio playback detected. Sound automatically disabled");
    DebugEngine.disableSound = true;
    return;
}
```

What is wrong with the try/catch?

The call stack looks like this:

> Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll!Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Helpers.ThrowExceptionFromErrorCode(int error) + 0x3d bytes 
>       Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll!Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.SoundEffect.AllocateFormatAndData(byte[] format, byte[] data, int offset, int count) + 0x107 bytes
>       Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll!Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.SoundEffect.Create(byte[] format, byte[] data, int offset, int count, int loopStart, int loopLength, System.TimeSpan duration) + 0x31 bytes
>       Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll!Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.SoundEffect.SoundEffect(byte[] format, byte[] data, int loopStart, int loopLength, System.TimeSpan duration) + 0xd1 bytes 
>       Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll!Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.SoundEffectReader.Read(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentReader input, Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.SoundEffect existingInstance) + 0x124 bytes
>       Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll!Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentReader.InvokeReader(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentTypeReader reader, object existingInstance) + 0xdf bytes
>       Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll!Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentReader.ReadObjectInternal(object existingInstance) + 0xfd bytes
>       Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll!Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentReader.ReadObject() + 0x4d bytes
>       Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll!Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentReader.ReadAsset() + 0x88 bytes
>       Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll!Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentManager.ReadAsset(string assetName, System.Action recordDisposableObject) + 0x129 bytes
>       Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll!Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentManager.Load(string assetName) + 0x2c7 bytes
>       Project_Ares.exe!Project_Ares.SoundEffectAres.Load(string location) Line 77 + 0x2c bytes    C#

Comment: Most likely because the assets are loaded from a different thread. If the exception isn't marshalled back to the calling thread the catch statement will not do anything.

Comment: XNA does not use separate threads for loading content, or pretty much anything else.  As far as I'm aware the only place where threading is potentially an issue is when interacting with the media player.

Comment: I find it difficult to explain the situation as you've described it.  Can you post a stack trace?

Comment: @ColeCampbell thanks for clarifying. I was only guessing, but threading is usually the reason for missing exceptions like this. If that is not the case here, it does sound a bit odd.

Comment: I added a stack trace above.

Comment: Are you using a first-chance exception handler?  Or do you have a debugger attached with the "break on all exceptions" setting turned on?

Comment: I am not sure. I use the default debugger in Visual Studio 2010. How do I set "break on all exceptions"?

Comment: It's in the menu under Debug > Exceptions, but it's off by default so if you didn't set it it seems unlikely that it would be turned on.  I'm afraid I'm at a bit of a loss, given what you've showed us.  I can't imagine any realistic scenario where the catch here would simply fail to execute.